# Kivy Interpolation on Canvas

Tags: python, image, canvas, textures, kivy

I am new to kivy and python. I am trying to have an texture (256x256) shown pixelated through my canvas, but it is blurred, and through some googling i think it is interpolated? I want it to show the pixels with sharp edging and not blurred. It also blends in color from surrounding tiles in the texture when i use texture.get_region(...) to select one tile (64x64) and display that, so i get a border from the other tiles in my new texture. I guess i am just really bad at reading Kivy's documentation.

```
    texture = Image('template.png').texture //getting texture
    topright = texture.get_region(64, 64, 64, 64) //Selecting a specific Tile
    with self.canvas:
        Rectangle(texture = texture, pos = self.pos, size = (512,512))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set

```
texture.mag_filter = 'nearest'
texture.min_filter = 'nearest'
```

You might only need one of these, I don't remember, but you can test and see the doc at http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.graphics.texture.html

Comment: Thanks, also I did only need {texture.mag_filter = 'nearest"} the other did not do anything